# iTunes review iOS 7 without send my app to background

Tags: objective-c, ios7, itunes, review

I know that for opening the rating page of itunes I should open from my app the url itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idAPPID where APPID is the id of my app. Although the result of this call send my application to background and opens itunes. Is it possible to open the rating page without leaving from my app, for example inside a web view?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SKStoreProductViewController* spvc = SKStoreProductViewController.new;
spvc.delegate = self; //self is the view controller to present spvc
[spvc loadProductWithParameters:@{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:@(APPSTORE_ID)}
                completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error)
                {
                    if (result)
                        [(UIViewController*)spvc.delegate presentViewController:spvc animated:YES completion:nil];
                }
];


-(void)productViewControllerDidFinish:(SKStoreProductViewController*)viewController
{
    [(UIViewController*)viewController.delegate dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```